# Autowired is null (basic example)

Tags: java, spring

My service:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMapper requestMapper;

  ... 

  // Somewhere I use the mapper...
  request = requestMapper.applicationToBasicRequest(application.get());

}
```

My Interface

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { BankAccountMapper.class, ApplicantMapper.class, ObligationsMapper.class })
public interface RequestMapper {

 ....
}
```

I get the following error when starting the application with Run As -> Java Application:

> Field requestMapper in project.service.MyService required a bean of type
>   'project.RequestMapper' that could not
>   be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

If I cannot put @Autowired in the interface, how do I initialize it?

Comment: You need to make an implementation of this interface.

Comment: @KamilW what do you mean by that?

Comment: Do you have a class that implements the `RequestMapper` interface? Where is the `applicationToBasicRequest` method implemented?

Comment: No. Why would I need that?

Comment: What is it going to inject if there is no implementation?

Comment: @user11114269 Post your pom file. Do you have   -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring as mentioned in [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/)

Comment: Have you defined any `component-scan` or `@Configuration` class? According to spring, your bean either does not exist or was not loaded into spring context.

Answer (score 0):

Make implementation class of RequestMapper interface, i.e. annotated with `@Service`

```
@Service
public class RequestMapperImpl implements RequestMapper{

 @Overried
 public Result applicationToBasicRequest(Object obj){
  // Do your work here
  return null;
 }

}
```

when you Autowired  `RequestMapper` in any controller then spring IOC container automatically inject `RequestMapperImpl` object into RequestMapper instance.

or you can give `@Qualifier` annotation for your specific dependency injection. it needs when you have multiple implementation class for single interface

Comment: It's all done by annotations in the interface like `@Mapping(target = "term", source = "proposal.term")`. There is no java code

Comment: My code now executes after I did the impl. My problem is that applicationToBasicRequest returns null. How can I do this if I don't have any code? What do I return?

Comment: you create impl class or what ?

Comment: `RequestMapperImpl implements RequestMapper` but I need to implement the applicationToBasicRequest and applicationToFullRequest methods. I don't have any code for this because this is all done by annotations